# DateTime::Event::Sunrise-question

Tags: perl, datetime

Why does that script say that sunrise is at 04:11:20 - it should be dark night at this time. [DateTime::Event::Sunrise](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3a%3aEvent%3a%3aSunrise)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Event::Sunrise;

my $dt = DateTime->new( year => 2010, month => 12, day => 22, time_zone => 'CET' );

my $sunrise_span = DateTime::Event::Sunrise ->new (
                    longitude => '48',
                    latitude =>  '16',
                    altitude =>  '-0.833',
                    iteration => '1' );

my $both_times = $sunrise_span->sunrise_sunset_span( $dt );

say "Sunrise is: " , $both_times->start->datetime;
say "Sunset is: " , $both_times->end->datetime;

# Sunrise is: 2010-12-22T04:11:20  
# Sunset is: 2010-12-22T15:22:01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given times are absolutely correct, in Central Europe time, for the latitude and longitude you specified (which is in Yemen).  Though Yemen is UTC+3, so in their local time, sunrise would be 6:11 and sunset 17:22.

Where did you intend to calculate sunrise and sunset for?

Comment: Well the most likely scenario would be `latitude => 48, longitude => 16`, which would be in Austria, which uses Central European Time.

Comment: Yes, it should be Austria - I confused this tow parameters. 6:11 and 17:22 would be nice.

Comment: Reversing the two gives 7:43 and 16:05